# Breeze validation message incorrectly using another validation context

Tags: validation, breeze

I have hit upon a problem with breeze validation.

It seems highly likely that the root cause of this particular problem is due to what looks like a design flaw in breeze. Specifically, that validation errors are **not assigned a copy of the validation message** generated by its validator. Instead the **message is generated each time using the context last supplied** to the validator.

This would not be a problem until you realise that validator errors generated from the same validator all share a reference to that same validator instance and that this validator instance uses the last context that was supplied to it to form the validation message.

The consequence of the above is probably best explained with the following scenario:

1. you have more than one instance of the same entity bound to a page
2. both entity instances break a rule defined by the SAME validator instance
3. for each entity instance, different context values are used
4. the two error messages generated for BOTH validation errors are determined by the last context supplied to the validator
5. therefore the message for the first validation error uses the context supplied for the second

Like I say, I think this is a design flaw but am happy for explanations why this isn't the case AND alternative means for avoiding the above scenario that don't feel like a hack.

Thanks

Comment: Would you mind putting a failing example in a plunkr or jsFiddle? That would make it much easier to understand, reproduce here, and fix. Thanks

Comment: Hi Ward, sorry about the late reply - I thought I would get a stackoverflow notification rather than having to "poll" myself. I'll have a go at getting that example over to you next week. I'm expecting it to be a non-trivial example in order to demo so it may end up slipping to the week after...

Comment: OK, I found the root cause of the "problem". The good news is that it was our incorrect use of breeze that was the culprit: we calling entityAspect.getValidationErrors() and then looping through the errors to build up a message string using the following code: errors += "\r\n" + entityErrors[i].validator.getMessage();

Comment: ** BAD NEWS **: it seems we can't use errors += "\r\n" + entityErrors[i].errorMessage due to an issue with not being able to tell a validator to use a translated property displayName. Will follow this up with another question.

Comment: ** GOOD NEWS **. I have dug into the breeze code and found that if I customize the property metadata and add a displayName with the translated property name, the validation message template is correctly parameterized with this value. Nicely anticipated Ward :-)